# run commands in subdirectories concurrently

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

I know how to run a command in all subdirectories that match a pattern like this (lets say I want to run `gh repo sync`):

```
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && gh repo sync) ; done
```

And runs the commands in a subshell in each directory *serially*.

What I want is to run all the commands in parallel but wait in the main script for them to all finish.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GNU Parallel does this excellently. I've been using [this structure](https://gitlab.com/engmark/tilde/-/blob/7d529258e67a23768cc850d165d02ec235b6c649/.bash_history#L645) daily for a long time:

```
parallel --wd '{}' 'gh repo sync' ::: ./*/.git/..
```

Similar test on my own system:

```
$ parallel --wd '{}' 'pwd' ::: ~/my\ projects/*/.git/..
/home/username/my projects/acard
/home/username/my projects/acp01
[125 more]
```

Comment: This looks awesome! Can I somehow see the output of the commands in the console?

Comment: A side note about this vs the other answer:  If the commands rely on shared resources and you need to limit how many run at one time, `parallel` has `-j` to set a maximum number of concurrent jobs.  Much more difficult to do that with the simple loop in the other answer, though that one doesn't require an additional dependency.

Comment: @traveh, of course _parallel_ preserves command output.  Moreover, I think you'll be able to drop `cd` using `--wd` option.

Comment: `GitHub` client output have some special characters in it. I think that's why it wasn't being shown for me, but `Git` works fine. Great, love it!

Comment: You have my vote anyway, but why do you have `&& cd -` at the end, just before the process exits?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I was writing on a phone without access to a Linux machine, so I overthunked it :)

Comment: if you don't want the added dependency you can do the same with xargs, but I don't remember what arcane syntax is required...that's why I always use parallel

Comment: @thegreatemu `man xargs` shows that it needs `-P` to run in parallel. But it doesn't seem to have much control other than # of processes.

Answer (score 12):

Run each subshell command in the background and then wait for them all to complete

```
for d in ./*/
do
    ( cd "$d" && gh repo sync ) &
done
wait
```

Comment: This is also a good answer, but I'm accepting the other one as it is better suited for my needs (sorry).